# Manipulando un DataFrame, ¿Como ir de tres columnas a 9?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

tengo el siguiente dataframe que al imprimir da el siguiente resultado. 3 columnas (Id, Punto A y Punto B), y necesito dividir en 9 y que salgan con sus nueves cabeceras respectivas (Id, Code A, LonA, LatA, ValorA, Code B, LonB, LatB, Valor B)

```
Id                   Punto A                       Punto B
0   1  ('SM-1', 495, 1579, 210)  (1.0, 4035, 860.8031, 164.0)
1   2  ('SM-1', 495, 1579, 210)  (2.0, 4035, 848.3031, 166.0)
2   3  ('SM-1', 495, 1579, 210)  (3.0, 4035, 835.8031, 168.0)
3   4  ('SM-1', 495, 1579, 210)  (4.0, 4035, 823.3031, 169.0)
4   5  ('SM-1', 495, 1579, 210)  (5.0, 4035, 810.8031, 170.0)
```

En este caso se usa Split?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según la imagen se puede ver como la columna `puntoA` es una tupla, asi que podemos realizar un for dentro de ella y generar nuevas columnas.

```
df[['puntoa1','puntoa2','puntoa3','puntoa4']] = pd.DataFrame([ x for x in df['puntoA'] ])
```

[image: Ejemplo]

Comment: y como seria incluyento el punto B?

Comment: df[['puntob1','puntob2','puntob3','puntob4']] = pd.DataFrame([ x for x in df['puntoB'] ])

Comment: Gracias, me ha funcionado despues de borrar las columnas Punto A y Punto B

Answer (score 0):

Puedes simplemente aplicar el constructor de `pd.Series` sobre cada "columna de la columna" mediante `pandas.Series.apply`:

```
df[["Code A", "LonA", "LatA", "ValorA"]] = df['Punto A'].apply(pd.Series)
df[["Code B", "LonB", "LatB", "Valor B"]] = df['Punto B'].apply(pd.Series)
```

luego usar `pandas.DataFrame.drop` para eliminar las columnas con las tuplas.

Un ejemplo completo reproducible:

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({"Id": (1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
                   "Punto A": (('SM-1', 495, 1579, 210),
                               ('SM-1', 495, 1579, 210), 
                               ('SM-1', 495, 1579, 210),
                               ('SM-1', 495, 1579, 210),
                               ('SM-1', 495, 1579, 210)),
                   "Punto B": ((1.0, 4035, 860.8031, 164.0), 
                               (2.0, 4035, 848.3031, 166.0), 
                               (3.0, 4035, 835.8031, 168.0),
                               (4.0, 4035, 823.3031, 169.0),
                               (5.0, 4035, 810.8031, 170.0))
                   })

df[["Code A", "LonA", "LatA", "ValorA"]] = df['Punto A'].apply(pd.Series)
df[["Code B", "LonB", "LatB", "Valor B"]] = df['Punto B'].apply(pd.Series)
df.drop(["Punto A", "Punto B"], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

> ```
> >>> df
>
>    Id Code A  LonA  LatA  ValorA  Code B    LonB      LatB  Valor B
> 0   1   SM-1   495  1579     210     1.0  4035.0  860.8031    164.0
> 1   2   SM-1   495  1579     210     2.0  4035.0  848.3031    166.0
> 2   3   SM-1   495  1579     210     3.0  4035.0  835.8031    168.0
> 3   4   SM-1   495  1579     210     4.0  4035.0  823.3031    169.0
> 4   5   SM-1   495  1579     210     5.0  4035.0  810.8031    170.0
> ```

Comment: Gracias, lo probaré